# Why can't I add foreign key constraints

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

this is my code:

```
CREATE DATABASE exams;

SHOW DATABASES;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS students(
    student_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    first_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    middle_name VARCHAR(40),
    last_name VARCHAR(40)NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
    password CHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    reg_date DATETIME NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (student_id),
    UNIQUE(email));

SHOW table status
INSERT INTO exams_3121(student_id, first_name, middle_name, last_name, email, password, reg_date)

CREATE TABLE entries
(
 entrie_id int NOT NULL,
 student_id int NOT NULL,
 subject_id int,
PRIMARY KEY (entrie_id),
FOREIGN KEY (student_id) REFERENCES student(student_id),
FOREIGN KEY (subject_id)REFERENCES subject(subject_id)
)
CREATE DATABASE subjects;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS subjects(
subject_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
subject_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
level_entery VARCHAR(40)NOT NULL,
exam_board VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (subject_id));

CREATE TABLE entries
(
entrie_id int NOT NULL,
entrie_id int NOT NULL,
subject_id int,
PRIMARY KEY (entrie_id),
FOREIGN KEY (student_id) REFERENCES student(student_id),
FOREIGN KEY (subject_id)REFERENCES subject(subject_id)
)
```

When I use this code it says cannot add foreign key constraint
and I don't know what to do. Please and thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't have a `student_id` column in the table. You have `entrie_id` twice.

Comment: Unfortunately, MySQL hides the actual error message when it comes to foreign key definition errors. You need to run `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` and find it in the *LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR* section. Please note that [show engine queries](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-engine.html) require the [`PROCESS` privilege](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_process), which your regular MySQL user may not have—you can either assign the privilege or run the query as root.

Comment: @Barmar I have a `student_id` column except it is in another table.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález SQL wont let me use SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS is there any other way thanks for help so far.

Comment: _**@Terrors_Edge**_: To understand the problem correctly, you better post `create` script for all the 3 tables. Basically, referred fields _**MUST match**_ in many things with those of the parents.

Comment: I figured out how to solve it, all you need to do is open it with an sql file with the source H:\SQL 3.sql

Comment: @Terrors_Edge How exactly does it not let you use it? Do you have a local server to develop or you're developing right in Production server?

Comment: You don't have a table named "student". You have a table named "students".

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems.

First, you got the names of the table you're referencing wrong. The name of the tables are `students` and `subjects`, but you wrote `student` and `subject`.

Second, the `entries` table has two `entrie_id` columns. One of them should be `student_id`.

```
CREATE TABLE entries
(
    entrie_id int NOT NULL,
    student_id int NOT NULL,
    subject_id int,
    PRIMARY KEY (entrie_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (student_id) REFERENCES students(student_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (subject_id) REFERENCES subjects(subject_id)
)
```

Also, if you're creating multiple databases and putting your tables in them, you'll need to refer to tables with their database prefixes if they're different from the one you selected as default with the `USE` command. As you've written it, you're not actually using the databases you created with `CREATE DATABASE`.